# how to prevent user from accessing a webpage without login

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have a page called jobboard.html that I only want the super user to access.

Right now I have created up to the point where the user can go to url /login/, enter their username and password, and then they are redirected to /activejobs/.

However, anyone can manually type in /activejobs/ into the browser and be directed there. I am not sure how to redirect someone (who does not have permissions) that types in /activejobs/ into the browser to the login page. I have some idea of using the POST data and getting the username and password to authenticate it with the inbuilt user database Django provides but I am not sure how to do it with my current set up.

urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

    urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'activejobs/login.html'}, name='login'),
      url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'template_name': 
      url(r'^activejobs/', include('activejobs.urls')),
    ]
```

login.html:

```
{% extends 'activejobs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py contains this line to make it redirect to activejobs url:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/activejobs/'
```

activejobs/urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    app_name = 'activejobs'

    urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', views.BoardView.as_view(), name='board'),
       url(r'^(?P<contactId>[0-9]+)/$', views.ViewContactDetails, name='detail'),
    ]
```

activejobs/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from getrate.models import ContactInfo
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

class BoardView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'activejobs/jobboard.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_jobs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ContactInfo.objects.filter(isActive = True)
```

I feel like in BoardView is where I handle the post data to authenticate the username and password, but I am not sure how to code that in.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Try using middlewares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class BoardView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

If your user is login,user will be auth by session auth,just check user is_authenticated when they access job list

Comment: works perfectly! I liked your solution the most as all I had to do was append this stuff to my current setup and not rework anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
@loginrequired
```

or something relate (the function have to run before the below function)

2 way, just check (should use user in rest api)

```
request.user.(bla bla)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use decorators.

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^about/$', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="secret.html"))),
```

In the class,

```
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: this also works if my views were functions but I was using generic views classes which LoginMixin works for. Thanks for giving me the exact terms to google and check out in the docs.

Comment: Sure :)  Glad to be of help.